# Can not encode emoticon in webApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Now I have a problem about encoding string  included emoticon character in WebAPI. The WebAPI is used by mobile (Andoid / IOS).

Header is sent from Mobile : 
 Accept-Encoding: gzip
 Accept-Charset: UTF-8
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Type: text/xml
 Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*

The string is "Test ". I used HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, and result is "Test " but the expected result is "Test &#128512 ;".